# Unwanted line-breaking of hyphenated word in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, line-breaking, citing, hyphenation

In .bib file:

```
@article{Kurahashi_Yokota2004,
author = "Kurahashi, M. and Yokota, A.",
title = "Agarivorans albus gen. nov., sp. nov., a $\gamma$-proteobacterium isolated from marine animals",
journal = "International Journal of Systematic and Evolutionary Microbiology",
volume = "54",
year = "2004",
pages = "693--697"
}
```

Output:

[image]

See that the `\gamma` proteobacterium word is broken up.  I want to keep the gamma together on the same line as proteobacterium.

Comment: Try to write it as `\hbox{$\gamma$-proteobacterium}`, but I'm not sure if this is good for a citation. AFAIK there is some non-hyphenating dash, but I can't recall its name.

Comment: Non-hyphenating dash, huh?  I'd be interested to know, if anyone knows what it's called.

Comment: @Martin @ptrcao It's called `\nobreakdashes` and is to be followed by the requested sequence of one to three `-`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write

```
title = "Agarivorans albus gen. nov., sp. nov., a 
         $\gamma$\nobreakdashes-proteo\-bacterium isolated
         from marine animals",
```

I've added a discretionary hyphen as the long word will probably create a badly underfull box, but hyphenating after "proteo" might be more acceptable.